# Install Samsung function key drivers in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, drivers, function-keys

After recently upgrading to Windows 8, I realised my function keys were not working. (In function mode.)

I assume I need some drivers for them. I tried searching the Samsung website (I'm using a Samsung notebook), but found nothing.

How can I use my function keys?

Model: NP300E5A-S01UK

Comment: You might consider posting your full model number.

Comment: @Moab have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After installing [SW Update](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/NP300E5A-S01UK-downloads) there was an option to install 'Settings' which includes drivers for the Fn keys.

You can also install other stuff (I installed a touchpad driver) from here.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the drivers of the previous version of Windows i.e. of  Windows 7, then try installing it. To a certain extent it may help.

Whenever upgrading to the future version of Windows you must inquire with the Samsung customer service whether they have created the drivers for it and is the laptop compatible with the new version of Windows?

Comment: [I don't see anything](http://www.samsung.com/uk/support/model/NP300E5A-S01UK-downloads) resembling a function key driver or software

Answer (score 1):

Samsung Settings (for Win 8) has limited functionality compared to Samsung Easy Settings (for win 7)and for you to get all the functionality back, here are the steps:

1. Downlod and install Samsung settings (Wind 8)
2. download Samsung Easy Settings for WIn 7 or if you have your DVD installer, then copy the setup folder to your HDD
3. Rename the setup.exe to setup1.exe
4. Install as admin and run in Win 7 Compatibility
5. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

This is my experience with a Samsung laptop (NP270E4E-K06VE) and operating system *Windows 7*.

The solution to the problem "FN key for controlling the brightness and mute audio not functioning correctly":

I proceeded to install:

- [Easy driver](http://www.drivereasy.com/)
- [Easy Settings](http://www.samsung.com/latin_en/support/model/NP270E4E-K06VE-downloads)

The steps I did:

1. Download the latest version 10.18.10.3643 of the Intel(R) HD Graphics Driver use Easy  driver, because Easy driver found the latest version of the driver.
2. Unpack Intel(R) HD Graphics Driver and install
3. Restart the computer and enjoy it!